# I have an issue with iterating a set

Tags: c++, class, templates, stl, set

I need to iterate through a set. The set is a set of Items which is a class I implemented. I have this error:

```
error C2662: 'double Item::getUnitPrice(void)' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const Item' to 'Item &'
```

This is the function where I iterate through the set, but I have the error in the 
"sum+= it->getUnitPrice();"

```
double Customer::totalSum()
{
    double sum = 0;
    set<Item>::iterator it;

    for (it = _items.begin(); it != _items.end(); ++it)
    {
        sum += it->getUnitPrice();
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate over your set:

```
double Customer::totalSum()
{
    double sum = 0f;

    for( std::set<Item>::iterator it = _items.begin(); it != _items.end(); ++it )
    {
        sum += (*it).totalPrice();
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: @MichaelUrman All lead to the same result. If you like one of those better, craft another alternative answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help but it stills gives me an error 
Error 1 error C2662: 'double Item::getUnitPrice(void)' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const Item' to 'Item &'

Comment: Please post your *full code*. I cannot help you with something that you may have done in your code without seeing it.

Comment: I did now. Thanks again

Comment: Sorry, but your error is about const-correctness and you don't have that anyway. It does not make sense to me. But you did not post all your code, so I cannot help you. Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This is the full code, besides the main, and the main only has return 0;

Comment: @user4384866 Please read the link I provided. Getting help here is largely dependent on making answering as easy as possible. I do not feel like copying all that stuff and thinking of a main that may or may not look like yours. That's time I could spend on someone who made it easy to answer his question. Read the link and prepare a *minimal* example. You should have done so *before asking*.

Comment: I read it and I edited this question because I can't post a new question

Comment: Sorry, I don't think you understood it completely. Post **a complete, compilable program** that I can copy and paste into my compiler/editor in one go and press "run". If I have to do *anything* more than that, your question is bound to be left in favor of another question where I can do that. Nobody here can somehow read thoughts over TCP/IP. Post a complete program.

Answer (score 0):

*I just don't know how to get to the unitPrice using a set.*

```
double Customer::totalSum()
{
    double sum = 0;
    set<Item>::iterator begin = _items.begin();   <<< Although clever compilers can make 
    set<Item>::iterator end = _items.end();      << this a futile attempt at optimization.

    for( set<Item>::iterator iter = begin; iter != end; ++iter )
    {
       sum += it->getUnitPrice();
    }
  return sum;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but it stills gives me an error 
Error 1 error C2662: 'double Item::getUnitPrice(void)' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const Item' to 'Item &'